# Call graph for a turbo pascal program

Tags: pascal, call-graph, turbo-pascal

I am doing some maintenance to a 18 year old pascal program. To help me understand how everything fits together I want to draw a call graph. However I cant find any software that can draw a call graph for pascal source. I am currently using Turbo Pascal 7 and have no idea about the abilities of other pascal compilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pascal analyser from Peganza maybe?

http://www.peganza.com/products_pal.htm

Commercial though, but description has "call tree" in it.

---

New URL:
https://www.peganza.com/products.html#PAL

Comment: Good. A previous employer had it, and I played with it from time to time, and had a good impression of it. It time, an update with experiences would be welcome. I have to convince my current boss :-)

Answer (score -2):

**[Code Visual to Flowchart](http://www.fatesoft.com/s2f/)** can help you visualize Pascal logic. Demo is free to try.

Comment: It can show the logic in a simple function. As soon as the function gets complex it chokes. It can also only function at function level and not at program level showing how everything fits together.

Comment: I couldn't remember the name of the other software that could help you, and wanted to search for it when I get home. Without +1 I didn't want to bother, and now seeing -1 I see I was right.